# Где лежит реализация метода spawnEntity в Bukkit?

Tags: java, minecraft

Имеется ядро Bukkit, хочу найти реализацию метода spawnEntity, захожу в entity/Entity.java, а там обычный интерфейс та и вообще, я обычного кода там не вижу, одни только интерфейсы. Помогите пожалуйста найти данный метод. Ссылка на ядро - [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/tree/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit)

Comment: Я не знаю, что такое mineCraft, но если там java то интерфейс не содержит реализацию метода, не считая функциональных интерфейсов,  метод описанный в интерфейсе реализуеттсяв классе. Соттветвенно  вам  нужен класс реализующий методы вашего интерфейса

Answer (score 1):

Метод spawnEntity для каждого наследника интерфейса будет свой. Посмотрите какой класс у того объекта, который вызывает данный метод, вот в тот класс идите и там найдете реализацию

Comment: а как я узнаю, что за класс?

Comment: а как ты узнал имя метода? Ты же где-то его взял

Comment: World.java - интерфейс

Comment: Я не знаю что тут ещё ответить потому, что тебе явно указали на то, как решить твою проблему. Более того, мне кажется, ты неправильно подходишь к тому, как разобраться в чужом коде. За тебя реализацию никто искать не будет, поэтому тебе нужно самому найти класс, который вызывает этот метод и посмотреть в нём реализацию. Используй ctrl+f  spawnEntity в конце концов, но важно научиться это делать самому, потом пригодится еще не раз.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не видишь обычного кода, а лишь интерфейсы, так как смотришь только API, чтобы посмотреть реализации, тебе надо копаться в собранном ядре, например попробуй декомпильнуть жарник или использовать [paperweight](https://github.com/PaperMC/paperweight)

Ну а реализация World.spawnEntity(...) лежит в org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R1.CraftRegionAccessor.spawnEntity(...)